# How to Let D-Link Router Connect Android with ADB over TCP?

Tags: android, networking, flutter, tcp, adb

I'm trying to debug Flutter apps with ADB over TCP, so tried the following (Android connected with USB) according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp/3623727#3623727):

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect <Android-ip-address>:5555
```

But I always get `unable to connect to <Android-ip-address>:5555: No route to host`.
I installed the plugin `Android WiFi ADB` to Android Studio, but...no hope.

After that, I tried to ping my Android phone from PC with that command `ping <Android-ip-address>`, but again it failed with that output `From <PC-ip-address> icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`.

Now I tried to do the same thing (PC & phone), however on an another router (Tenda) and it worked like a charm.

So the problem is from my router, which is a D-Link with a firmware version `ME_1.03`. I searched for "Port Forwarding" and stuff like that, but I don't know what I'm doing and I didn't come up with any result.

What can I do to solve it.

Comment: WAPs can be configured for Wi-Fi isolation that prevents one Wi-Fi device from communicating with other Wi-Fi devices. You router may have such a configuration for its WAP, and you may or may not be able to change it,

Comment: @RonMaupin Yep, I solved it as you said, but It's called here "Relay Blocking ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it. It's because of a feature (as others said) called WIFI/User Isolation in routers. But in my case, it's called Relay Blocking. Anyway, you have to disable it.

In `D-Link (DSL-2740U) - Firmware Version ME_1.03`:

Main Page ---> Advanced ---> Advanced Wireless Settings ---> **Relay Blocking**.
Check disabled choice.

Comment: That is actually a feature of the WAP, not the router. Traffic on the same network doesn't pass through the router. You have a Frankenstein box with multiple devices in it. If you had the devices separately, you would configure it on the WAP, not the router.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about router type (in case it doesn't use something different from TCP/IP,  Lol). You need to double check, that both devices inside one local network.

Without any additional settings on router, your IP address could be like this `xxx.xxx.xxx.***`. Where part with `xxx` should be same both both device. When this is done, follow instruction [from the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp/3623727#3623727). Please note, **you will need to connect devices with USB**, before using TCP.

Comment: @TN888 Both devices, your laptop and android phone?

Comment: 100% sure. Also, I tried other phones. Still failed.

Answer (score 0):

The firmware can be found [here](https://tsd.dlink.com.tw/) below `DSL` > `2750U`, while there are 2-3 different hardware revisions, therefore it is rather unclear which device it actually is - for some revisions there is newer firmware. Generally, the router's network bridge in between wired LAN and WiFi needs to be enabled, in order to connect. Just see the router's [manual](http://files.dlink.com.au/Products/DSL-2750U/Manuals/DSL-2750U_AU_User%20Manual.pdf) on page 33 and 45. Without that bridge, you could only connect `adb` from a notebook, through the same wireless network segment, as the smartphone is connected to (unless "User Isolation" is enabled on the router).

Comment: "User Isolation" was the cause. But here, it's called "Relay Blocking". I disabled it.